# KDE 4.13.2 update breaks login from LightDM on Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, login, kde, lightdm

One of the KDE updates that rolled out in the last couple of days broke my ability to log in to KDE from lightdm using the `lightdm-kde-greeter`. At the lightdm prompt, I enter my login credentials, the dialog boxes disappear, and nothing happens.

System: Kubuntu 14.04 on KDE 4.13.2

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to re-install the kde-workspace-bin package, which was removed by an update on 6/23/14 for some reason.

```
sudo apt-get install kde-workspace-bin
```